# PHP & jQuery live search on table issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, livesearch

I have a JS file to livesearch a table. It works fine and shows the results on the page when you search.

Javascript:

```
function Search()
{
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide();
});
}
```

HTML

```
 <table class="table" id="table">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search" onkeyup="Search();">
    <tr>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Personeelsnummer</th>
        <th>Geblokkeerd niveau</th>
        <th>Wachtwoord</th>
        <th>Verwijderen</th>
        <th>(De)blokkeren</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['P_Naam'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['P_ID'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['P_Blocked'];?></td>
```

The code goes on with some more buttons in the table.

The issue is that when it returns the search the table headers dissapear. I've been trying to figure out what the problem is but cant seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you select

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
```

it selects also those headers:

```
<tr>
    <th>Naam</th>
    <th>Personeelsnummer</th>
    <th>Geblokkeerd niveau</th>
    <th>Wachtwoord</th>
    <th>Verwijderen</th>
    <th>(De)blokkeren</th>
</tr>
```

and deletes them.

Try to change the jQuery filter to skip the first row.

Comment: Thanks for the quick input, however I have no idea how I would do that.. Is there a way I can exclude those headers?

Comment: Try that - $('#table tr:not(:first)')

Comment: My pleasure :) glad I could help